# JPA + Hibernate + Spring + OneToMany delete cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I've read some related questions but they are not exactly the same problem as mine.

I'm using JPA + Hibernate + Spring and I want to do something that I'm not sure if it is possible just with config.

I have my domain classes with a more or less complicated relation. There are many elements that are related with one element (like if it was a tree many elements are sons of one element).

Something like:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Foo parentNode;
    ...
}
```

Which will get a table like:

```
Foo id    parent_id
1
2         1 
3         1
```

When I delete row with id = 1 I want to delete rows with id = 2 and id = 3 (it may be recursive, elements with parent_id = 2 and parent_id = 3 would be deleted as well).

For some restrictions I only can have the relation in son's side with the parent_id reference.

My question is: is it possible to do this with JPA or Hibernate configuration or do I need to do some recursive function to delete all children and all parents?

I've tried with:

```
@OneToMany(name = "PARENT_ID", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

And I've read that maybe using Hibernate annotations.

If anyone can give me some clue I'm lost at this point.

### Edit 1

Would it be possible to do like:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Foo parentNode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentNode", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Foo> childs = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
    ...
}
```

Keeping the table as is, with the fk to the parent?
I've tried this but I keep getting the same error, fk restriction violated.

### Edit 2

Finally solved with:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Foo parentNode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Foo> childs = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
    ...
}
```

This `@OneToMany` is needed even if we do the mapping in our BBDD by refering just the parent id.

Now when we delete a Foo with childs, it's childs will be deleted as well.

Thanks for your time and good advices!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Relationships in JPA are always unidirectional**, unless you associate the parent with the child in both directions. Cascading REMOVE operations from the parent to the child will require a relation from the parent to the child (not just the opposite).

So here you need to change unidirectional relationship to bi-directional.

for more details refer to:

- [JPA: unidirectional many-to-one and cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197181/jpa-unidirectional-many-to-one-and-cascading-delete)

Comment: Thanks but I need this in ManyToOne side, since I don't have OneToMany way. Would it be possible? Thanks

Comment: So if I can't have this bi-directional, do I need to do some recursive process? Thanks

Comment: Yes you have to refer http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/

Comment: I've seen this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToOneCascadeRemove.htm they do remove a many-to-one relation but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

Look at `@OneToMany`'s [orphanRemoval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval()) option:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Here there is a complete explication about `CascadeType.REMOVE` and `orphanRemoval`:

- [@ManyToOne JPA association and cascade... not sure what happens if I delete an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190149/2295657)

Good luck!